# wp_localize_script $handle

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, javascript, wp-localize-script

Can anyone tell me what the "`$handle`" ( first parameter ) of `wp_localize_script` is normally used for. Thanks.

P.s.: I have no idea why but stackexchange is telling me this question dosen't meet quality standards.

Edit: When i put in my ps it accepted it so i suppose it's the length of the quesion.... if you feel like this is an unacceptable question then apologies

Comment: @kaiser was the edit you did to do with the problem i was having - eg something to do with how i wrote the code in the post - i will go look it up in the faq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's basically a unique id of the script you registered or enqueued before.

Let's say we enqueued a two scripts with [wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script):

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script_1','/js/some_script.js' );

wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script_2','/js/some_other_script.js' );
```

Now you want to pass your `$data` to the script #2 with [wp_localize_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script):

```
wp_localize_script( 'my_script_2', 'my_script_2_local', $data );
```

After this - when WordPress prints out your `my_script_2` it will print out your `$data` variables along with it so you can use them in your script.

As you can see `my_script_2` is our handle here - it makes the link between our script functions.

Answer (score 0):

The handle is arbitrary (as in not technically meaningful) name of script that is used for human convenience when declaring it with `wp_register_script()`/`wp_enqueue_script()`.

So first you declare script (or look up handle of already declared one) and then you can use handle to assign localization object to it with `wp_localize_script()`

Comment: Seems like I can't answer a single Q today. Everybody beats me by seconds :)

Comment: @kaiser Wow guys you're fast!! Nice to see you.

Comment: @Maugly we sit in the chat and it pokes us about new posts :)

Answer (score 0):

`$handle` is for all the `script` and `style` functions the given name.

```
// @example: 
wp_register_style( 'my-example-script', '/path/to/scripts/script.js', 'etc.' );
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-example-script' );
// or
wp_localize_script( 'my-example-script' );
```